# Incorporate small angular feature in my wordpress site

Tags: plugin-development, customization

I want to add an angular feature in my wordpress site, but i m confused how to incorporate both. I m jus confused about folder structure for the same Or i can create a plugin??
My angular feature is ready i jus have to incorporate the same in my site.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information in the question. What do you currently have?

Comment: I have created a cart module. When user will click on add to cart wp data will be getting added in the angulars cart module, and for cart details and all angular will manage, only during checkout angular will pass the data to wp and wrap up the checkout process.

Comment: creating module helped me.